# Java: javadocs of arrays type

Tags: java, arrays, api, javadoc

I am searching for something like javadocs for the arrays in Java. What methods, what their signatures and what they do. I got this problem, because IDE (Intelij) if you click on the called method of the array with pressed cntrl, shows nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Java Language Specification [§10.7. Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. `length` may be positive or zero.
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
> - All the members inherited from class `Object`; the only method of `Object` that is not inherited is its `clone` method.

Comment: thank you, this the one that I was searching for, bad that I havn't noticed it by myself(

Answer (score 2):

There is no such javadoc.

But arrays don't have any other method than the one in java.lang.Object. They have a single, read-only attribute: `length`. They implement Serializable and Cloneable.

For useful methods regarding arrays, look at the class `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: No, it doesn't change its signature. If it did, it wouldn't override it.

Comment: ou, you are right, signature contains only parameters and the method name